# An issue with using LinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

I am using `LinearModelFit` to estimate *four* alternative model specifications on a small sample of *12* observations.

The models I'm using are

1. ordinary linear model: $y=c+d_1D_1+d_2D_2+bx+k(x D_2)$
2. log-linear model: $log(y)=c+d_1D_1+d_2D_2+bx+k(x D_2)$
3. lin-log model: $y=c+d_1D_1+d_2D_2+blog(x)+k(log(x) D_2)$

and

4. log-log model: $log(y)=c+d_1D_1+d_2D_2+blog(x)+k(log(x) D_2)$

The $D_j$'s are indicator variables and $y$ has its first two entries equal to *zero*, which poses a problem in the estimation of model specifications *2* and *4* ($log(0)\rightarrow-\infty$); to proceed with the estimation procedure, I simply replace the leading *zeroes* with $-1000$, when appropriate.

After comparing the output from `LinearModelFit` to that of another software, I realized that the estimated models *1* and *2* produced the same results (estimated parameters, standard errors, p-values) and differed in the values of $R^2$, adjusted $R^2$ and $AIC$ (*Akaike info crit*).

On the other hand, the output for models *3* and *4* were completely different between the two software.

Of all the observed discrepancies, I [*know*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82792/timeseriesmodelfit-incorrect) that the values of $AIC$ can be attributed to different scaling used on different platforms; what seems troubling is the discrepancies observed in the rest reported values.

I reproduce the output from `LinearModelFit` along with the data used in the end notes; also, I include a sample script and accompanying data and output from the other software I used.

I am confused and I would like some help troubleshooting this problem. Up until now, I had no reason to consider either software as more '*reliable*', so I don't know where to start.

Please note, I have also tested slightly different specifications of `LinearModelFit` (eg, switched `IncludeConstantBasis` on/off with the appropriately required change in input data) and done analogous changes in the other software; the results did not change; the discrepancies persisted.

---

### End notes

```
(* function used to extract information from LinearModelFit output *)
info=Grid[{#[{"ParameterTable"}], {"RSquared", "AdjustedRSquared", "AIC"} -> #[{"RSquared", "AdjustedRSquared", "AIC"}] // Thread // Riffle[#, Null] & // Row // List, #[{"ANOVATable"}]} // Riffle[#, {{Null}}] &, Alignment -> Left]&
```

**model 1**

```
table=Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPSuNlYGAoZgESPpnFJWmsyLxiEC85Pw/IYgKyXAwhlFExI5CqAJOVqDoyQWIQAogZimbNBILImQ5gHjalDDD1RevcH1aJNEwmRqkISC3LRIfML4yElO6Qa30dmFDnkHmHlZBSYxBYXOaQuYObkFKgmTvkcvMcMgvECSmN6T/0VeNMgUOmgDoepQzwEHjXQ8BbYKVBIH9drCTgLYSpdsUEvMUA99bdTALeAitNA4G+HIi3ANOjdlY="];
data=Rest[table];
xs={const, D1, D2, x};
fs={const, D1, D2, x, D2 x};
lmf=LinearModelFit[data, fs, xs, IncludeConstantBasis -> False];
info[lmf]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

*Eviews* output

> [image: Blockquote]

**model 2**

```
table=Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPSuNlYGAoZgESPpnFJWmsyLxiEC85Pw/IYgKyXAwhlFExI5CqAJOVqDqKGMDggz06g4GhaNZMIIic6RBkD+TpGhoYGOgZ4AGGxkDC2MLS3DjB0FTP0tTEFMg2NzC0BOo0w28r0DK4yDr3h1UiDZPpbKsIyFqWiQ5FSTs2WB66LeFAvNYdcq2vAxPqHIpUf0bf2OMgS4JWYxBYXOZQZLhAdo4TswIJWoF27pDLzXMouuDMe0YtTZEErTH9h75qnClwKBIL3bp7Y7YSsVqBDHDkvOshOZiAjCBQOF2sJDmYYLbaFZMcTEAGOJjuZpIcTEBGGgj05SCCCQAessDY"];
data=Rest[table];
xs={const, D1, D2, x};
fs={const, D1, D2, x, D2 x};
lmf=LinearModelFit[data, fs, xs, IncludeConstantBasis -> False];
info[lmf]
```

> [image]

*Eviews* output

> [image]

**model 3**

```
table=Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPSuNlYGAoZgESPpnFJWmsyLxiEC85Pw/IYgKyXAwhlFExI5CqAJOVqDqKGMDggz06g4GhaF9b3Gn+ibIOcBH8WoE64CK/F4gcz2qRIUfrtK/h17/+kIZqdah3IF5rQf11px37JKBaC6aToDXFZuGP2RPFYVqXk6B15sQHbPN/icK0bidB68PdnhxCCWJQrR2HidUKZLhP6djXE0R6MAEZm+0KzvpJkB5MQMbx74vkLV+LkRxMQEbQXiUbpxDSgwlkq/50p9U7RRHBBACX3ZNg"];
data=Rest[table];
xs={const, D1, D2, x};
fs={const, D1, D2, Log[x], D2 Log[x]};
lmf=LinearModelFit[data, fs, xs, IncludeConstantBasis -> False];
info[lmf]
```

> [image]

*Eviews* output

> [image]

**model 4**

```
table=Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPSuNlYGAoZgESPpnFJWmsyLxiEC85Pw/IYgKyXAwhlFExI5CqAJOVqDqKGMDggz06g4GhaF9b3Gn+ibIOQfZAnq6hgYGBngEeYGgMJIwtLM2NEwxN9SxNTUyBbHMDQ0ugTjP8tgItg4v8XiByPKtFhs62Tvsafv3rD2mHoqQdGywP3ZZwIF5rQf11px37JByKVH9G39jjIEuC1hSbhT9mTxR3KDJcIDvHiVmBBK0zJz5gm/9L1KHogjPvGbU0RRK0PtztySGUIOZQJBa6dffGbCVitQIZ7lM69vUEkR5MQMZmu4KzfhKkBxOQcfz7InnL12IkBxOQEbRXycYphPRgAtmqP91p9U5RRDABAAErv1g="];
data=Rest[table];
xs={const, D1, D2, x};
fs={const, D1, D2, Log[x], D2 Log[x]};
lmf=LinearModelFit[data, fs, xs, IncludeConstantBasis -> False];
info[lmf]
```

> [image]

*Eviews* output

> [image]

[*This*](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_1JkXEiG8scbCVFWabRgVpfXzWzWkQG/view?usp=sharing) is a link to a zip file containing files '*eviews_data.csv*' and '*replicate.prg*'. Extract both files at a directory of your choosing; to run '*replicate.prg*' please edit the first command by inserting the full path to file '*eviews_data.csv*'.

Comment: Just looking at Model 3, the statistical package *R* gives the same values as *Mathematica*.  You might want to try dividing the dependent variable by 1,000 and run the *Eviews* analysis again.

Comment: I know this is not directly related to your concern about the differences in the results but...(1) Fitting 6 parameters with just 12 data points is likely not going to be very reliable, (2) Plugging in -1,000 for the log of zero is not a standard recommendation, and (3) Wanting to perform model selection on top of only having 12 observations with 6 parameters is expecting a bit too much.

Comment: @JimB thanks for running the numbers; wouldn't scaling y by 0.001 simply scale the coefs proportionately? 1) I know 2) I kinda know; also what would be considered 'standard practice' in such a situation (drop the zeroes, interpolate them-somehow-in place, other choice ?) 3) I wasn't doing model-selection; I started from model 4 just to get a rough point estimate of the elasticity; usually, I cross-validate my results-that's how I figured out there was something wrong

Comment: on a related note, model 4 in Eviews is probably correct because doing the calculations by hand yields an elasticity of -1.05 which is 'close' to -1.885-all things considered; I can understand that it's possible to get the coefs wrong but how can you get the $R^2$ wrong, is beyond me, hence the post

Comment: About the dividing by 1,000:  some software packages just apply the textbook formulas which can be very susceptible to round-off error when you have very large numbers as you do with this data.  About plugging in something when an attempt to take to the log of zero:  one way is to plug in the number that is half-way between zero and the smallest positive number.  But for anything that is done, it really ought to be checked with respect to the subject matter and the residuals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of a mistake by the OP.  In the *Mathematica* code the `Log` is taken not once but twice for the variable labeled `x`.  That is why the differences occur among the results from different packages.  That issue would have been more readily evident if the short dataset was not shown in just compressed form.

Comment: I'd like to say I haven't made such mistakes in the past but I can't.  (And that certainly includes the future.)

Comment: please don't close it before I have a chance to award a bounty to @Jimb for taking the time to work with my code and data; for the record, I thought using compressed data would be easier to the eye when going through the question-I was wrong; I wrote the code for this twice from scratch, and still did it wrong... thanks '@JimB'

Comment: You had a good question that needing solving.  It's just that it's unlikely to help anyone else, that's all. No reason to take it personally.  And for many (most?) of us, getting points is not at all why we frequent this site.  Just glad we can help.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and where you're coming from; there's a  misunderstanding; I'm not taking anything personally; I just wanted to reciprocate the favor somehow as I know what it's like to work on someone else's code and data and awarding a bounty is not allowed until after a couple of days the question is asked; I really appreciate the people and content of the community and at the time simply felt like the appropriate way to respond; please feel free to do whatever is necessary as per community guidelines; thanks again and sorry for any misunderstanding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question should be closed because of a mistake by the OP.  In the *Mathematica* code the `Log` is taken not once but twice.  That is why the differences occur among the results from different packages.  That issue would have been more readily evident if the data was not shown in just compressed form.

For Model 2 the data has the original value of `x`:

```
{{1., 1., 0., 1622.4, -1000.0}, {1., 0., 1., 1248.02, -1000.0},
 {1., 0., 1., 1089.12, 6.21461}, {1., 0., 1., 486.02, 7.31322}, 
 {1., 0., 1., 362.2, 8.00637}, {1., 0., 1., 243.41, 8.69951},
 {1., 0., 1., 268.76, 9.21034}, {1., 0., 0., 925.76, 6.21461}, 
 {1., 0., 0., 413.12, 7.31322}, {1., 0., 0., 307.88, 8.00637}, 
 {1., 0., 0., 206.91, 8.69951}, {1., 0., 0., 228.45, 9.21034}}
```

For Model 4 the value of `x` is now `Log[x]`:

```
{{1., 1., 0., 7.39166, -1000.0}, {1., 0., 1., 7.12931, -1000.0}, 
 {1., 0., 1., 6.99313, 6.21461}, {1., 0., 1., 6.18625, 7.31322},
 {1., 0., 1., 5.8922, 8.00637}, {1., 0., 1., 5.49475, 8.69951}, 
 {1., 0., 1., 5.59382, 9.21034}, {1., 0., 0., 6.83062, 6.21461}, 
 {1., 0., 0., 6.02374, 7.31322}, {1., 0., 0., 5.72971, 8.00637}, 
 {1., 0., 0., 5.33228, 8.69951}, {1., 0., 0., 5.43132, 9.21034}}
```

But Model 4 takes the log again:

```
xs={const, D1, D2, x};
fs={const, D1, D2, Log[x], D2 Log[x]};
lmf=LinearModelFit[data, fs, xs, IncludeConstantBasis -> False];
```

That is why the results differ between *Mathematica* and *Eviews* (and *R* and *SAS*).